# Возможно ли отправить сообщения в скайп через post или get http запросы?

Tags: ajax, http, post, get, skype

Всем привет.
как отправить сообщение в скайпе через http, и возможно ли такое в принципе?

Comment: Кажется, нет. Официально поддерживается Desktop API, для его использования вам нужен инсталлированный Скайп, с которым и общается API.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я представляю, нет, поскольку скайп использует не http-протокол.